# how i can use 2 condition in where linq

Tags: c#, linq

my code not answer

```
var SabteGheybat = from row in db.InfoStudents.Where(p => p.PayeTahsili == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
                && p.Gheybat != Mydate)

                               select row;
```

Comment: What does "my code not answer" mean? What errors do you get? What results don't match your expectations?

Answer (score 0):

If there is an error please provide error information to everyone.
If your query has no error message then it looks like you forget `lazy` query.
please use `ToList()` because your query is legal.

```
var SabteGheybat = (from row in db.InfoStudents.Where(p => p.PayeTahsili == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
                && p.Gheybat != Mydate)
    select row).ToList();
```

i try the same logic and it's result:
[image]

and you can simplify query like:

```
var SabteGheybat = db.InfoStudents.Where(p => p.PayeTahsili == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
                && p.Gheybat != Mydate)
```

Comment: you can simplify query like: var SabteGheybat = db.InfoStudents.Where(p => p.PayeTahsili == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
                && p.Gheybat != Mydate)

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting error you need change your code like this:

```
var con = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
var SabteGheybat = from row in db.InfoStudents.Where(p => p.PayeTahsili == con
        && p.Gheybat != Mydate)
```

OR use this format:

```
var con = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
var SabteGheybat =  db.InfoStudents.Where(p => p.PayeTahsili == con
        && p.Gheybat != Mydate).toList()
```

Comment: Nothing row to choose

Comment: are you getting data if remove where clause?

Comment: I do not delete the data. We find that you see the information you provided